# Polling mechanism through an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, polling

I need to add polling mechanism to call a web service through my web page. For that I am trying to use an `ajax` call inside a `javascript` page. I am very new to `ajax` and `javascript`. I wrote the below code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
         function pollServerForNewMail() {
            setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
                alert("TEST");
                poll();
            }, dataType: "json"});
        }, 10000);
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

What I need is to fire the alert TEST in every 10 seconds. Anybody please help me on this.

I will edit the post with my two jsp files.

index.jsp file

```
<html>
    <table style="width:100%;text-align:center;'">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;width:100%">                               
<a href="polling.jsp?reset=true"><img src="images/import.png" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

polling.jsp file

```
         <html>
            <head>
                <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                     function pollServerForNewMail() {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
                            alert("TEST");
                            poll();
                        }, dataType: "json"});
                    }, 10000);
}
        pollServerForNewMail() ;  

          </script>
            </head>
            <body>
       </body>
        </html>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your problem, I mean: once you return a value from your server side application, then js should fire the alert

Comment: Actually I need to invoke an endpoint through this ajax call. The endpoint should be invoked in every 3 minitues through this ajax call.

Comment: So what's exactly your problem? In that code the only problem I see is that your request must return a value before before run another request, so if your request take loger than 10s it will "desynch"

Comment: I have two jsp files. From index.jsp file I'm calling to polling.jsp file. I need to appear the alert TEST in every 10 seconds. It should firstly appear with the polling.jsp page load. But I tired above code it does not work. So please help me to fix the problem

Comment: Then you should also add code from polling.jsp

Comment: yes I added the above code in polling.jsp page. I called the function inside script tags as below. <Script>pollServerForNewMail();</script>. But I did not get the alert at least one time.

Comment: Ok Dheed. But im bit confused. Please suggest me a way to appear the alert TEST in every 10 minutes. Should I call setTimeout function separately than the pollServerForNewMail().

Comment: Also to do the first call on page load you should call `pollServerForNewMail()` (the best time should be when the page is loaded so js will not block the render of the page)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73315/discussion-between-hasanthi-and-dheed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my  problem by changing polling.jsp file as below. I will add my solution.

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var set_delay = 5000,
                    callout = function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            /* blah */
                        })
                                .done(function (response) {
                                   alert("TEST");
                                })
                                .always(function () {
                                    setTimeout(callout, set_delay);
                                });
                    };
            callout();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will fire a timer only once.

Use `setInterval` to execute code every X seconds:

```
function pollServerForNewMail() {
    setInterval(function(){
        // Code in this function will run every 10 seconds

        $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
            alert("TEST");
            poll();
        }, dataType: "json"});
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: What if the request doesn't receive a response before the established time? Is almost the same approach of the author, but he prevents the stack of requests, because he runs a new ajax once the previous ends

Comment: you could easily change it back to setTimeout and call the function again once ajax return, but thats not how i understood the author..

Comment: I used setTimeout. But it did not appear the alert at least once. Actually I need to firstly appear the alert at the page load. After every 10 seconds it should dispalyed. Do you have any idea why it did not call at the page load. I just put the function name inside script tags to call the function at page load.

Comment: add the entire html page to your question

Comment: I added my two pages to the question.

Comment: in `polling.jsp` there is a missing `}` at the end of pollServerForNewMail function

Comment: sorry. when I copying the code here, there was a mistake. But I have put it in the code. Let me just edit the post. But still it does not work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73308/discussion-between-hasanthi-and-user3906922).